# MVVM Light Target for RaisepropertyChanged

Tags: c#-4.0, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have the following code in a listener object, to evaluate if this message is for that listener:

```
 (this, (action) => { if (action.Target.GetType() == typeof(MainViewModel) && (action.PropertyName == "EditionMode" ))
```

The code of the sender:

```
set
         //  ...
               RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyProperty, oldValue, value, true);
         //  ...
```

but I can't find  the right overload to set the Target.

Answer (score 1):

To call RaisePropertyChanged you need only pass the property name as a string argument:

```
RaisePropertyChanged("MyProperty");
```